# How to select element after Ajax Load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have inputs in my html:

```
<input type="text" id="1" value="1" name="1">
<input type="text" id="2" value="2" name="2">
```

And than i use ajax and load put  another one input:

```
<input type="text" id="3" value="3" name="3">
```

There is javascript file with code:

```
$('input[type=text]').focusin(function() {
    var Id = this.id;
    someActionWithId(Id);
}).focusout(function(){
    var Id = this.id;
    someActionWithId(Id);
});
```

Can some one tell me why i cant pick input that is loaded by AJAX. Maybe some one can suggest some solution? Thanks.

Comment: you need to delegate event: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind event for dynamically loaded elements like this :

```
$(document).on('focusin','input[type=text]',function() {
    var Id = this.id;
    someActionWithId(Id);
});
$(document).on('focusout','input[type=text]',function(){
    var Id = this.id;
    someActionWithId(Id);
});
```